# I want to use the descriptive text of variable A and relate them with descriptive text of variable B to predict B. How do I do this?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, predict

I am currently exploring NLP and wonder if there is any technique that allows me to use the descriptive text associated with a variable A in order to predict variable B by leveraging the descriptive text associated with variable B.

Do I use the descriptive text of B as an additional feature or do I try to associate/predict words or topics from the variable A text to the words or topics of variable B text?

Real-world example close enough to actual use-case: I have a bunch of legal documents with paragraphs of text which I am using to predict multiple policies. Each policy has an ID and multiple policies can be associated with each legal document. I believe I can leverage descriptive information (policy title and description) about each policy in this process and relate them to the legal documents. How do I go about solving this problem? Any ideas would be useful.

Comment: You are speaking about many things, similarity, predictions, topic extraction. Do you have a [mcve]?

Comment: @NathanMcCoy unfortunately while I cannot describe the actual use case in detail, I can try to provide a close enough example. I have a bunch of legal documents with paragraphs of text which I am using to predict multiple policies. Each policy has an ID and multiple policies can be associated with each legal document. I believe I can leverage descriptive information (policy title and description) about each policy in this process. How do I go about solving this problem? Any ideas would be useful.